# Suspended Laptop Cannot Wake Up - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, crash, suspend, acpi

I've got an ASUS G73JH, and whenever I suspend it or hibernate it, it will not wake up. The screen stays backlight but is black. The fan remains running, however the HDD does not, not disk activity is noticeable (audibly (It's not a SSD)).

I can't:

- Awaken it with the keyboard
- Awaken it with the mouse
- Soft power-off by pressing the power button
- Change virtual screens by pressing Ctrl-Alt-#
- Restart X by pressing Ctrl-Alt-Backspace

I have to hold down the power button and shut it down that way, and this seems a little unreasonable. Is there a place I could look for more detail as to what's causing this? Is there a known quick-fix to this issue?

Nothing is logged as happening when the system is in "suspend" mode.

---

Here's what happened immediately before and after the suspend "happened," note the time gap:

```
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 1)
May  4 17:48:57 tofu kernel: imklog 4.2.0, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

This one's kinda long, here's what happened immediately before the suspend, I'm not sure if it'll help but if you can find a use for it:

```
May  4 17:46:10 tofu anacron[3353]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2010-05-04
May  4 17:46:10 tofu anacron[3353]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.775927] CPU0 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.775958] CPU1 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.775987] CPU2 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.776138] CPU3 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.776168] CPU4 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.776197] CPU5 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.776200] CPU6 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.776229] CPU7 attaching NULL sched-domain.
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919611] CPU0 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919668]  domain 0: span 0,4 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919699]   groups: 0 (cpu_power = 589) 4 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919733]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919762]    groups: 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178) 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178) 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178) 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919850] CPU1 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919852]  domain 0: span 1,5 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919881]   groups: 1 (cpu_power = 589) 5 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919912]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.919915]    groups: 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178) 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178) 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178) 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920003] CPU2 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920005]  domain 0: span 2,6 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920033]   groups: 2 (cpu_power = 589) 6 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920065]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920093]    groups: 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178) 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178) 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178) 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920155] CPU3 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920157]  domain 0: span 3,7 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920185]   groups: 3 (cpu_power = 589) 7 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920217]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920245]    groups: 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178) 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178) 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178) 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920307] CPU4 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920335]  domain 0: span 0,4 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920337]   groups: 4 (cpu_power = 589) 0 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920368]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920397]    groups: 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178) 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178) 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178) 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920459] CPU5 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920487]  domain 0: span 1,5 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920489]   groups: 5 (cpu_power = 589) 1 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920520]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920549]    groups: 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178) 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178) 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178) 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920611] CPU6 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920639]  domain 0: span 2,6 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920641]   groups: 6 (cpu_power = 589) 2 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920699]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920701]    groups: 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178) 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178) 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178) 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920762] CPU7 attaching sched-domain:
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920791]  domain 0: span 3,7 level SIBLING
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920793]   groups: 7 (cpu_power = 589) 3 (cpu_power = 589)
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920851]   domain 1: span 0-7 level MC
May  4 17:46:10 tofu kernel: [ 2241.920853]    groups: 3,7 (cpu_power = 1178) 0,4 (cpu_power = 1178) 1,5 (cpu_power = 1178) 2,6 (cpu_power = 1178)
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  Sleeping...
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (wlan0): now unmanaged
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (wlan0): device state change: 8 -> 1 (reason 37)
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (wlan0): deactivating device (reason: 37).
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, dhcp client pid 1984
May  4 17:46:12 tofu kernel: [ 2244.084515] wlan0: deauthenticating from 68:7f:74:23:02:ae by local choice (reason=3)
May  4 17:46:12 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.2 on wlan0.
May  4 17:46:12 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.2.
May  4 17:46:12 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  Policy set 'Auto eth0' (eth0) as default for routing and DNS.
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (wlan0): cleaning up...
May  4 17:46:12 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (wlan0): taking down device.
May  4 17:46:12 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:4c6e:638a:0:1e4b:d6ff:fe78:951d on wlan0.
May  4 17:46:12 tofu wpa_supplicant[1212]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): now unmanaged
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): device state change: 8 -> 1 (reason 37)
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): deactivating device (reason: 37).
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, dhcp client pid 1559
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <WARN>  check_one_route(): (eth0) error -34 returned from rtnl_route_del(): Sucess#012
May  4 17:46:13 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.3 on eth0.
May  4 17:46:13 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.3.
May  4 17:46:13 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): cleaning up...
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): taking down device.
May  4 17:46:13 tofu avahi-daemon[1176]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:4c6e:638a:0:4a5b:39ff:fe0b:325d on eth0.
May  4 17:46:13 tofu NetworkManager: <info>  (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 1)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem on a desktop machine (Ubuntu 9.10).  I'm forced to shutdown and not suspend/hibernate.

Comment: FWIW, I see this on Ubuntu 12.10, but only occasionally. This could be because I'm running xscreensaver (perhaps some particular screensaver does it - OpenGL, perhaps?), it appears to start up normally, but then blanks the screen and remains unresponsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have an Asus G73JH laptop with Ubuntu Lucid loaded.  I was having suspend issues as you were.  I came across this posting and tried out the steps detailed in post #7:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9261807

I can now suspend the laptop successfully, and can even resume without any issues (at least, none so far that is).

Hopefully this can work for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the system logs and the X logs for errors.

If this happens again, try switching to a new virtual screen (ctr-alt-1) (numbers go beyond 1.. but it's a good test)

If you can see a display and are prompted for login credentials, then you have an X issue.

Also, try to reset X with ctr-alt-backspace).

If the system really is asleep (no disk activity etc.) you may have hibernation issues related to an invalid configuration (e.g. have not specified valid partition etc.)

Edit:

Well, if the system really is asleep, then you may a more serious problem.
I've had two issues similar to yours.
In one case, xscreensaver would crash the system (my guess was it failed to play well with acpi/apm)
The other case was a laptop failing to undock / redock.

I dod think this is power management related, and I had no luck troubleshooting. My "fix" was upgrading the distro, which is a bit extreme.

One other thought is that you may want to disable CPU power management and NIC power management.  My guess is that your hw is locked in a 'bad' state due to improper power management.

Comment: The system will not respond to any input, I tried the above commands, none of them had any effect. I did this while trying to suspend, also, not hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with a Dell E1405. It will suspend, but when I turn it back on, the backlight comes on but the screen is black and it doesn't respond to anything - no keyboard, no network, nothing.

But I found that this only happens if I close the lid before it is fully suspended - if I hit suspend but wait a few seconds before closing the lid, I've had no problems getting it to resume.

Comment: I've tried just re-awakening it without ever having closed the lid and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

My Lucid occasionally doesn't wake up fully - no display activity too. At first I had to reboot the computer until I guessed to connect via ssh to it. I checked all logs, e.g. in `/var/log`, and the only sign I found out about the issue is

```
[drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id
```

in dmesg' output.

Fortunately, gdm restarting wakes up my display finally, so I got the workaround.
But I still want to fix the issue the right way.

I think this issue relates to this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/993941

Answer (score 1):

I have an Asus X53T laptop, with Radeon HD 7670M graphics, run Ubuntu 12.04. I tried a number of fixes for this suspend bug, none of which worked. The last solution I tried, and possibly the most basic to implement was to install the latest graphics card driver (AMD Catalyst™ 13.12 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver). Now suspend works absolutely normally. Good luck; hope this solution is of help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my new hp pavilion laptop. I close the lid, computer goes to suspend(power light blinking); when I open the lid, power light comes on, but display does not switch on (not even backlight comes on) and no harddisk activity.

Using ubuntu 10.04.

Seems to be an ubuntu bug since so many of us are having this problem.